# Regular expression excluding a word

Tags: regex

I want to match strings

```
\begin *** \end
```

where `***` does not contain `\begin`.

So far, I have tried

```
\\begin(?!\\begin)\\end
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative look ahead at each character:

```
\\begin((?!\\begin).)*\\end
```

Note that this will match the 2nd `\begin` and the `\end` in the input

```
\begin foo \begin bar \end bar
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

If you want to match a *whole* string that looks like that, wrap it in `^` and `$`:

```
^\\begin((?!\\begin).)*\\end$
```

Comment: This can get a bit weird, q.v. [here](https://regex101.com/r/xQ0tV4/1).

Comment: What does it mean a whole string?

Comment: You should always place the . after the lookahead, otherwise it will match, if the first character is part of the unwanted word.

Comment: Can you post another answer @SebastianProske?

Comment: @Seb good point. I've incorporated your comment into the regex

Comment: @Colas I don't think it's worth posting this as another answer, as Bohemians approach is correct, just mixed up a bit.